# Favicon doesn't show up on a new tab Chrome Extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, favicon

I'm building a `Chrome Extension` which overrides the new tab. I managed to override the new tab with my HTML file and also the page title. However, the favicon doesn't show up on the new tab with no errors showing up.

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello World",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "hello_world.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Here is `hello_world.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"/>
</head>  
 <body>
  <div>Hello World</div>  
 </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't find anything in the [`docs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) regarding favicon on a new tab.

Comment: Should `favicon.ico` not appear somewhere in your manifest file?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `favicon.ico` to [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in your manifest, so that your `hello_world.html` can access it. And then you have to change the `href` of your favicon dynamically to the result of `chrome.extension.getURL("favicon.ico")`.

Add this to your manifest: `"web_accessible_resources": [ "favicon.ico" ]`

**EDIT:** Deleted code sample because it didn't work and added a new one.

This code just works if you override the `history` or `bookmarks` page because they have a favicon by default. Just change this in the manifest to try out and edit the `head` of `hello_world.html` to the code below.

```
<title>Hello World</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="chrome-extension://{ID OF YOUR EXTENSION}/favicon.ico" />
```

Sadly it isn't possible to add a favicon to the `newtab` page. I hope you can live without it ;)

Comment: Your problem is, that the `newtab` page doesn't have a favicon by default.  You can try it with the `history` or `bookmarks` page because these two have one, but it won't work with `newtab`.

Comment: How did you conclude that?